# Connect Zoom with Codeigniter (curl)

Tags: php, http, curl

I want connect Zoom with Codeigniter, but I have a problem.

I created a ZOOM app (Waiting for Zoom approval) and I have a client id and redirect_uri.
I defined client_id, client_secret and redirect_uri.

```
$hash = base64_encode($client_id . ':' . $client_secret);
$headers = array(       
    'Authorization: Basic ' . $hash 
); 
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://zoom.us/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id='.$client_id.'&redirect_uri='.$redirect_uri);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array('data'=>($data))));

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$all=json_decode($result);               
print_r($all);
```

When I execute this code, I got stdClass Object ( [status] => [errorCode] => 202 [errorMessage] => Something went wrong. Please refresh this page. [result] => ).

Can you help me? Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're mixing up two steps of the OAuth process.

The OAuth flow should look like this:

1. You redirect your user to the authorize URL (the URL you have listed in your request) with your `client_id`, `grant_type`, `redirect_uri`, and `scope`.
2. The OAuth provider (Zoom) redirects your user back to your `redirect_uri` with a query string parameter of `code`
3. You make a `POST` request to the token endpoint with your `client_id` and `client_secret` in the `Authorization` header (which you have in your `$headers` variable) and the `code`, `redirect_uri`, and `grant_type` in the body (url form encoding, typically). The return value of this request includes the access token (and refresh token).

It looks like you mixed up the request in #1 with the request in #3.

You might consider using a managed OAuth service to do this for you, like [Xkit](https://xkit.co) where I work. There you just have to provide your Zoom OAuth credentials and they handle all the redirects, requests, etc. All you do is make an API call to Xkit and they'll return an access token. Here's their [Zoom Setup guide](https://docs.xkit.co/docs/zoom) for reference.